# LWC rules for folders

Tags: salesforce-lightning

Is there anywhere a place where the rules regarding the folder structure is explained?
The most important one I understand, i.e. lwc must be the name of the parent folder of components, and can be referenced with c/.

Other than that, I don't know; there seem to be issues with having folders / files with the same name (I think) even when they belong to a different component.
I can't tell for sure because I'm having different compilation errors all the time.

> I can't seem to reference subfolders properly without getting
>   compilation errors.

Sometimes when I change the name, one file is fixed then the other breaks.

Have been spending all day trying to fix basic import issues, seems like that thing is completely broken and I strongly regret that I have to work with it.

It seems that they use the @Babel/traverse npm library to compile (while we can't use npm directly, another thing that makes me wonder what the hell they're doing).

Some help is appreciated, although I'm afraid the community is tiny. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the following information will save you a LOT of trouble. 
Not applying these rules will result in obscure compilation errors during the bundling process:

•   Components should all be stored below a folder named ‘lwc’, this will place the components directly under the namespace c/;
•   No duplicate component names should ever exist under the c/ namespace;
•   You should not use ‘-‘ in component names, only alphanumeric characters and underscores;
•   Component folder names should be unique, they should not correspond to folder names that are places directly in the root of the project;

Best is to deploy regularly and check if anything broke.

Personally I really don't like it because this is WAY too restrictive IMO.
But anyway, it works now.